# The tailwind part of the classes does not work, but only on one Angular 17 page

Tags: angular, tailwind-css, angular-components, postcss

I was just writing code without making any global changes, and suddenly my tailwind broke. Namely, its class "p" and derivatives. Padding just stopped working for me. But not in all elements, but only in a certain component of the app-accordion-item.

I think the error is in the app-accordeon-item, but I can't figure out where

I have already tried reinstalling modules and dependencies, reloading the code, restarting the site, running in different modes: "npm start", "npm run dev:ssr", removing various components.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

upd: try to move your layout from the component to the level of your page and just run it. It seems that the problem is more nesting and tailwind does not understand which classes it needs to compile, but as soon as you take out the layout with its classes above, it compiles them. It remains only to delete this layout and that's it, because the styles are already compiled.